# How to plot time interval data using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data.frame like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)    
tasks <- c("Review literature", "Mung data")
    dfr <- data.frame(
      name        = factor(tasks, levels = tasks),
      start.date  = c("24/08/2010 01:00:01", "24/08/2010 01:00:10", "01/11/2010 01:30:00", "01/11/2010 02:00:00"),
      end.date    = c("24/08/2010 02:00:00", "24/08/2010 03:00:00", "01/11/2010 02:00:00", "01/11/2010 04:00:00")
    )
    mdfr <- melt(dfr, measure.vars = c("start.date", "end.date"))
```

I would like to plot this data using ggplot2 so that different dates are on different facets and only time portion is show on x-axis? I tried something like:

```
ggplot(mdfr, aes(as.Date(value, "%H/%M/%S"), name)) + 
   geom_line(size = 6) +
   xlab("") + ylab("") +
   theme_bw() + facet_wrap(~as.Date(value, "%d/%m/%Y"))

Error in layout_base(data, vars, drop = drop) : 
  At least one layer must contain all variables used for facetting
```

Comment: You can save yourself a lot of headaches by using the 'lubridate' package, instead of the 'as.Date' function.

Comment: One thing, related to your problem or not: I think you miss a % in `as.Date(value, "%d/%m/Y")`. Try `as.Date(value, "%d/%m/%Y")`.

Comment: Thanks, it produces the same error. I updated the question

Comment: Maybe I'm being a bit thick here, but what are you trying to plot, exactly? You want time on the x-axis, but what are you plotting on the y-axis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Added to your melted data frame two new columns `value2` and `date`. `value2` is `POSIXct` class of your times and `date` column contains just date part of your original `value` and converted to factor to use for faceting.

```
mdfr$value2<-as.POSIXct(strptime(mdfr$value, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"))
mdfr$date<-as.factor(as.Date(strptime(mdfr$value, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")))
```

Now you can use new value2 as x and date for facetting. I used `facet_grid()` with `scales="free_x"` and `space="free_x"` to get evenly spaced time intervals in both facets.

```
ggplot(mdfr, aes(value2, name)) + 
  geom_line(size = 6) +
  xlab("") + ylab("") +
  theme_bw() + facet_grid(~date,scales="free_x",space="free_x")
```

[image]